# Circular clockwise graph drawing

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw the graph $K_{3,3}$ and put the nodes in a *circular placement* where the nodes coordinates lie in the unit circle, by using Tkiz package.

Here is my current code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[shift={(3,0.7)}]
  \graph { subgraph K_nm [clockwise,nodes={draw,inner sep=0.1pt, fill=blue, circle, scale=0.6},n=3,m=3]};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But I get the following strange picture:

[image]

And I want to draw something like this layout:

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a complete example we can compile. Please also say how the output differs from what you want.

Comment: You have both `n` and `m` as `3`. Don't you want one of them to be `2`? Don't know if that's what you don't like, though.

Comment: You are right it supposed to be n=3,m=3. But this is not what makes the different that I'm wishing for. I will soon upload an good output example.

Comment: Please can you also complete your code so it is compilable?

Answer (score 3):

Please post complete code. I spent longer figuring out how to reproduce the original image than how to produce the new one. You obviously know the manual has the library call wrong, else it wouldn't work for you either, so why not make it easy for people to help you and provide the required preamble?

Like this, possibly?

[image: possible graph]

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing,graphs.standard}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[shift={(3,0.7)}]
    \graph [simple] { 
      subgraph K_n [n=6, clockwise, nodes={draw, inner sep=0.1pt, fill=blue, circle}];
      {1,2,3} --[induced complete bipartite] {4,5,6}
    };
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for comparison, here is `k33` in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html), first in the conventional layout, then in a circular layout.

[image]

In MP there is no special syntax for graphs:  once you have mastered defining points, drawing lines, filling paths, and the syntax for loops you can draw more or less anything using the same small set of syntax.   Of course, if you want to, you can define your own macros to draw graphs.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    % some magic to make us the same vertical size as fig 2.
    undraw fullcircle scaled 120;
    undraw fullcircle scaled 12 shifted (point 6 of fullcircle scaled 120);
    drawarrow 60 right -- 72 right withcolor red;

    % define the nodes
    48 = -x1 = x3 = -x4 = x6;  x2 = x5 = 0;
    36 = y1 = y2 = y3 = -y4 = -y5 = -y6; 

    % connect them as per K_33
    for i=1 upto 3:
        for j = 1 upto 3:
            draw z[i] -- z[(i+j) mod 3 + 4];
        endfor
    endfor

    % mark each node
    for i=1 upto 6:
        fill fullcircle scaled 12 shifted z[i] withcolor 3/4[blue, white];
        draw fullcircle scaled 12 shifted z[i];
        label(decimal i, z[i]);
    endfor
endfig;
beginfig(2);

    % define the nodes on a circle this time
    for i=1 upto 6:
        z[i] = point 4 + 4/6 - 8/6 i of fullcircle scaled 120;
    endfor

    % the rest is the same
    for i=1 upto 3:
        for j = 1 upto 3:
            draw z[i] -- z[(i+j) mod 3 + 4];
        endfor
    endfor

    for i=1 upto 6:
        fill fullcircle scaled 12 shifted z[i] withcolor 3/4[blue, white];
        draw fullcircle scaled 12 shifted z[i];
        label(decimal i, z[i]);
    endfor
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

This is wrapped up in `luamplib` so compile with `lualatex`.  Or adapt for pdflatex with [`gmp`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/gmp?lang=en), or for plain MP.